# Вытягивание таблицей стилей из JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Хочу использовать функцию "[Аккордеон](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible)" из библиотеки JQuery.

Есть ссылка на таблицу стилей задействованною в данном примере по адресу:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css";
```

Как я могу увидеть данную таблицу стилей или задать свою, чтобы функция аккордеона работала?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. У вас какая-то ошибка в последнем предложении, либо оно не раскрывает суть проблемы, перечитайте свой вопрос и опишите его более подробно.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы увидеть данную таблицу стилей достаточно скопировать данную ссылку в адресную строку браузера, а оттуда уже можно и закинуть в IDE.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, что такое IDE?

Comment: @SvArt713 Это интегрированная среда разработки, другими словами это тот редактор, в каком вы пишите код, если это только не обычный блокнот. В web сфере популярными являются, например, Sublime Text, WebStorm, Notepad++ и прочее.

Comment: То есть скопировать код из панели разработчика?